# how to match only one relationship between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, match

i am using neo4j graph db ,it used in Ruby on Rails ,
for example:
i have 3 relationship between tom and jerry ,they cooperated to build 3 houses,  and now i just want to match 1 of 3 ;how to write the query code???
 i have tried this:  this is my code:

```
Neo4j::Session
             .query("MATCH (s1:Scholar)<-[r:COOPERATE]-(s2:Scholar) WHERE s1.id = #{@scholar.id}  RETURN  DISTINCT r ")
```

and the result is all relationship between s1 and s2 were founded

i just need 1 of relationship between s1 and s2 (i want to find all relationship in my db ,but i just need one between every 2 nodes)

how to fixed it??

Answer (score 4):

To get only one relationship for each related node:

```
MATCH (s1:Scholar)<-[r:COOPERATE]-(s2:Scholar) WHERE s1.id = {s1_id} RETURN s2, collect(r)[0] AS r
```

Note that I'm using parameters which are more secure (if the data is coming from a user) and allow Neo4j to cache your query.  To use parameters in the neo4j-core gem:

```
session.query("MATCH (s1:Scholar)<-[r:COOPERATE]-(s2:Scholar) WHERE s1.id = {s1_id} RETURN s2, collect(r)[0]", s1_id: @scholar.id).map(&:r)
```

There is also a query building API which would look like this:

```
session.query
  .match('(s1:Scholar)<-[r:COOPERATE]-(s2:Scholar)')
  .where(s1: {id: @scholar.id})
  .return('s2, collect(r)[0] AS r')
  .map(&:r)
```

Note that this will use parameters for you.

Also if you use the `ActiveNode` module from the `neo4j` gem (as opposed to making raw queries) you could do something like;

```
class Scholar
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  id_property :id

  has_many :in, :cooporates_with, type: :COOPERATE, model_class: :Scholar
end

Scholar.find(@scholar.id).cooporates_with(:s2, :r).return('s2, collect(r)[0] AS r').map(&:r)
```

Comment: id is a parameter ,and i just want to find 1 and only 1 relationship between 2 nodes  ,i can find result ,but there are too many relationships between 2 nodes and  their relationship are COOPORATE , i just need 1

Comment: I think I understand and I've updated the answer.  Does that work?  You need to include s2 because Neo4j automatically groups by non-aggregate columns in a `RETURN` or `WITH`

Comment: it works ,thank u very much  ,but i don't know why must add s2  in return ?? it doesn't work when i delete s2 in return

Comment: Neo4j doesn't have a `GROUP BY` like SQL does.  In this case the `collect` is an aggregation function so it automatically groups by the other columns in the `RETURN` (in this case it's just `s2`).  If you want to speed things up a bit by not returning the `s2` values you could end instead with `WITH s2, collect(r)[0] AS r RETURN r`